Unable to access External Workbook PhpSpreadsheet on laravel
I have this issues where i get this error "Unable to access External Workbook".
I'm trying to convert an xlsx file into a pdf or html but on writer save i get this error.
I tryed in two ways:
$xml = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$xml->setIncludeCharts(true);
$spreadsheet = $xml->load($localTempFile);
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->writeAllSheets();
$writer->save('throwing_excel.html');

or
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setIncludeCharts(true);
$document = $reader->load($localTempFile);
$writer = new Dompdf($document);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->save('throwing_excel.pdf');

The error is thrown when I call the save method on the last row.
I tryed with pdf or html but i have the same error.

Acutally I found the file was corputed so i fixed that and it is worked but i still have a problem with charts where i have data from other sheets, I get this error: "Call to a member function getDataValue() on false".
I want to save just the 3rd sheet with all the charts but doesn't work because some of that charts contain data from previouse sheets.
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->setSheetIndex(2);
$writer->save('throwing_excel.html');
